# Field of discrete logarithms of a generator of a finite group

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, cryptography

Suppose that $\mathbb{G}$ is finite group of order $p$ ($p$ can be a prime number if necessary) and that $g$ is a generator of $\mathbb{G}$. What is the field of discrete logarithms of $g$?

I can see that the set $g^\mathbb{Z}\simeq \{1,\ldots p-1\}$ is finite and contains $p$ elements, it also has a commutative group structure with $0$ as neutral element, so it is (isomorphic to) $(\mathbb{Z}_{p-1},+)$. Addition is determined by
$c:=a+b$ with $c$ determined by $g^c:= g^ag^b$.  This is the discrete logarithm problem

But how can we deduces that there is also a multiplication? Can we derive it from the group law and the generator?

Because $(g^a)^b \neq g^{a \cdot_{\mathbb{Z}_p}b}$ in general.

Comment: $g$ is a generator of $G$. So $G$ is cyclic. Now consider the exponents.

Comment: I see how addition work, because $g^a\cdot g^b= g^{a+b}$, but I don't see how multiplication works.